# Use jQuery to change font and background color of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is one related question, but it is more advanced than this. I am simply trying to use jQuery to change both the background color and text color of the button holding my footer. The click on function is working fine with the background color, but the text is not changing colors. What am I missing? Here is my jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").on("click", "footer", function() {
        $(this).css("font-color", "#ff99ff");
        $(this).css("background-color", "#000066");
    });
});
```

Here is a link to the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qjawmyu1/

Comment: Use jQuery to add a CSS class to the button. And use CSS to change the font and background color of button.

Comment: `$("button").on("click", "footer", function() {` huh? `<footer>` inside `<button>`.

Comment: `<footer>` inside `<button>`?? Sure looks like selectors are reversed

Comment: There is no such css value as font-color.  It's just color. And the way to n do this would be  to make a class in css and apply/ toggle that with jquery

Comment: Even if that'll work it is considered bad practice to use block-elements inside `button`. If you're not using it as button, I'll suggest to remove it and just keep `footer`.

Comment: Yes, I realize it is not best practice for the footer to be inside the button, but that wasn't the issue here. My concern was simply why the click on method wasn't changing the font color. As expected, a very simple reason, I had the selector wrong. Thanks all for advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The property to change the font color is not `font-color` but just `color`

So you can try something like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").on("click", "footer", function() {
       $(this).css("color", "#ff99ff");
       $(this).css("background-color", "#000066");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

The CSS property to set the font colour is just `color`. Note that you can use a single call to `css()` if you provide an object. Try this:

```
$("button").on("click", "footer", function() {
    $(this).css({
        color: '#ff99ff',
        backgroundColor: '#000066'
    });
});
```

Also, it's considered better practice to keep your styles in a separate stylesheet and use jQuery to add/remove classes from elements only. Try this:

```css
.active {
    color: #ff99ff;
    background-color: #000066;
}
```

```js
$("button").on("click", "footer", function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Finally, your placement of a `footer` inside `button` element is invalid. You should reverse those elements.

Comment: something weird here? `$("button").on("click", "footer", function() {`

Comment: You need to get the css property name with quotes $(this).css({
        "color": '#ff99ff',
        "background-color": '#000066'
    });

Comment: @kpucha that's not true, quotes are not required for the keys in the object.

Comment: No, you really don't. You seem confused between object syntax and JSON.

Comment: @kpucha No, quotes are not necessary for the object keys. If the key contains special characters, then key should be wrapped in quotes. If you're not convinced, try that code.

Comment: Do a snippet and you will see, because he use the key from jQuery 1.8 to set browser property like webkit... and the - in background-color will get you an error...

Comment: @Rory where is the - there? with multiple words setter background**-**color you need the quotes

Answer (score 4):

Set up CSS classes for both states (before and after clicked), then simply call JQuery's [removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) and [addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) inside your action/event method.

Also, you can make your code simpler by using **IDs** for your button element and calling the JQuery [click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) function instead.

**CSS:**

```
button .button-default {
    ...
}

button .button-clicked {
    color: #ff99ff;
    background-color: #000066;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('button-default');
    $(this).addClass('button-clicked');
});
```

Credit to [Tushar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2025923/tushar) for mentioning this in another answer.

Comment: **1.** Use `$(this)` inside the handler to access the element that is clicked. **2.** You can chain methods on the same selector.
**3.** No need of removing the default class when the CSS is properly written.

Use `$('button').click(function() { $(this).addClass('button-clicked'); });`

Comment: 1. Right, I've updated my answer. 2. True, but I make it a point to show clarity in my code and I don't think it performs any better. 3. Also true, if you are overwriting everything you need to in the previous class(es). I'd rather overwrite the entire class, especially if you are using CSS libraries like Bootstrap. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanna swap the footer and button around
from

```
$("button").on("click", "footer", function() {
```

to

```
$("footer").on("click", "button", function() {
```

as i guess the button is inside the footer and the footer is not inside the button

Comment: You can use **[JQuery multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)** to achieve this result in a more efficient way

Comment: yes, but have nothing todo with click delegation, as in this case i think he has them the wrong way around.